# Encrypting PKs exposed via an API to protect from DDoS attacks

Tags: databases, api

Here is a simple scenario.

I have an endpoint `/person/:id` that returns persons information from the database. When `:id` is not known, resource is looked up from the database. A malicious user can use this information to intentionally create requests that would not exist in the cache and therefore the API to query the database.

I can scale the web services to infinity (*and beyond!*), however I cannot scale the database (due to the licensing restrictions).

Therefore, I can encrypt the PKs (e.g. using [aes](/questions/tagged/aes)) and require that the resulting encrypted IDs are used to query the API. **The benefit of this approach is that API can tell whether the ID is a valid ID without needing to consult the database.**

I'd like to know whether this has any drawbacks or if this is a known design pattern and there is a name I can Google.

Comment: Could you explain why you think the API would be able to tell whether the ID is valid?  Do you mean that, when decrypted, they match some known schema for an id, which you intend to keep a secret?

Comment: Correct. Though, there is no need to keep the schema secret. It can be a simple prefix check. There is no need to keep the schema secret because you'd need to have the password used to encrypt the ID in the first place, to generate a new ID.

Comment: I can think of a few possible downsides: If your password gets found out, and you have to change it, those encrypted IDs all change, so anyone relying on bookmarked URLs will suddenly not be able to find their friends.  Also, if someone is being malicious, it might cause a lot of load if you're constantly spending cycles decrypting junk, which might not stress your database, but could cost you a lot in terms of autoscaling instances.  Afraid I don't know of a special name for this approach, but maybe someone else will.